# Mini displayport monitor: How to connect to displayport?

Tags: video, gpu, displayport

I have the following problem:
 I bought a [Samsung SR75](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/monitors/uhd-and-wqhd/32-sr75-4k-uhd-space-monitor-ls32r750uenxza/) monitor, which has 2 ports for video input: HDMI 2.0 and a miniDP 1.2. I already use the HDMI port to connect my desktop workstation, but I also want to connect my HP laptop which has a displayport output.

Is the miniDP to DP cable bidirectional? What do you suggest to use for this scenario?

Comment: The cable should work fine (I assume you want to display your laptop screen on the monitor). I couldn't find a decent photo of the ports but if you look closely at the icons next to the ports it should have a little arrow on it indicating the direction of data flow.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the cable is bi-directional.

I have my home monitor connected via DP in the PC and miniDP in the monitor, so I can confirm this setup can work.